# Insert documents into mongodb using `insertmany` method of pymongo ignoring "InvalidDocument"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a extremely large data set(which is extracted for nginx log files), and some of the keys of the documents contain `.`, which may lead to `invaliddocument error`.

Instead of filtering out these invalid documents or replace the dots inside the keys, I prefer just ignore these documents, is there any  way that I can ignore the invalid documents when `insert_many` with `pymongo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can "ignore" errors on an insert_many by setting the ordered=False parameter; however this still fails for an invalid document [apparently by design.](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1809)

You can, however, do something like this:

```
import pymongo
import bson.errors

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

data_to_load = [{"ok": 1},
                {"ok": 2},
                {"not.ok": 3},
                {"ok": 4},
                {"ok": 5}]

for item in data_to_load:
    try:
        db.testdata.insert_one(item)
    except bson.errors.InvalidDocument:
        pass

for item in db.testdata.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
{'ok': 1}
{'ok': 2}
{'ok': 4}
{'ok': 5}
```

Comment: thank you, this is a good answer for solving the `invalid document error` issue, however the performance of insert_one is a little poor compared to insert_many. I would rather check and rename each invalid key of the documents.